# How do you use depth_image_proc?

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since there is no tutorial for this, how do I use these nodelets to convert a Kinect depth image into a PCL point cloud?

```
kinect -> point_cloud_xyz -> cloud
```

or do I need to use convert_metric?

```
kinect -> convert_metric -> point_cloud_xyz -> cloud
```

and if I want and xyzrgb pcl cloud (note this is a simplification and I don't know if I need convert_metric)

```
kinect -> register -> point_cloud_xyzrgb -> cloud
```

I would greatly appreciate an example roslaunch file if anyone has it.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31831/how-do-you-use-depth_image_proc?/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's one that I use: https://gist.github.com/2400165 .  It assumes depth_registration is turned on.  In answer to your question, you do need convert_metric, to convert from mm to m.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1